# tricky mySQL query with date calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tricky query i need to build in *MySQL* and just can't get it. tried many different ways. I have a field named `revuePeriod` which is an integer indicating the number of months between checkups. I have another field called `installDate` which is a date field. I want to return only records where the install date PLUS the `revuePeriod` is BEFORE today so in essence show `if (installDate + (revuePeriod x months)) < today` I can easily do something where the interval is hard coded, like :

```
SELECT * FROM cameras WHERE DATE_ADD(installDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < CURRENT_DATE
```

What's tripping me up is how to make the number of months decided by the field `revuePeriod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you have table "temp" with fields "installDate" & "revuePeriod".[image]

Then you can do this query

```
select date_add(installDate, interval revuePeriod * 3 month) AS f from temp HAVING f < CURRENT_DATE;
```

with result:

[image]

Is this like you want?

Comment: I think it is what he wants, besides the *3 part ;)

Comment: Thanks Jef, that was exactly what i needed, i just needed to change the 3 to a 1 and it is perfect. Thanks so much